# Is 做 necessary in the sentence 我不打算做决定 (wǒ bù dǎsuàn zuò juédìng)?

Tags: usage

I'm asking about this [jukuu.com](http://jukuu.com/show-%E6%89%93%E7%AE%97-8.html) example sentence:

> 我不打算做决定
>   <sub>(wǒ bù dǎsuàn zuò juédìng)</sub>

(Jukuu.com's translation is "Susan, I don't plan to make any decisions Susan" which is clearly wrong.)

It breaks down logically:

- [我](http://dict.cn/%E6%88%91) = I
- [不](http://dict.cn/%E4%B8%8D) = don't
- [打算](http://dict.cn/%E6%89%93%E7%AE%97) = plan
- [做](http://dict.cn/%E5%81%9A) = to make
- [决定](http://dict.cn/%E5%86%B3%E5%AE%9A) = to decide

So it means something along the lines "I don't plan to make a decision".

**Question**: Is 做 necessary in the sentence 我不打算做决定?

I'm not sure why 做 is in this sentence, but it seems unnecessary to me.  I.e., I would expect 我不打算决定 to be an acceptable sentence, but I'm unclear on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

决定 in 我不打算决定 is a verb (I don't plan to decide)

决定 in 我不打算做决定 is a noun (I don't plan to make decision)

'做**决定**' means 'make **decision**'

- in 我不打算决定 the object is omitted, It emphasizes the verb 'to decide'
- 我不打算做决定 is a complete sentence. It put emphasis on the object 'decision'.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's no good to omit the `做`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes `我不打算决定` is acceptable, and has the same meaning with `我不打算做决定`. But with the usage of `做` (which makes `决定` a noun, i.e. the decision) the emphasis is put on the action of *making the decision*.

---

<sup>BTW: As a native Chinese I'm curious too; do `decide` and `make the decision` have the same meaning in English? Is there any nuance?</sup>

Comment: 打算 means 'plan to'. It is different from  决定 (decide to). When you plan to doing something, you may or may not actually do it. When you decided to do something, you are going to do it unless you change your mind.

Comment: @TangHo I think the point of the question is `决定` vs `做决定`, not `打算` vs `决定`, ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wrote "decide to make decision" (决定做决定). That would sound very strange.

Comment: For your question, Let me put it in another example-  'murder' and 'commit a murder'. In "he murders" the object is omitted. The emphasis is on the action of 'murder'. If you say "he committed a murder", the emphasis is on the object noun 'murder'.  Similarly, "he decides" emphasizes the action of 'decide' ;  while "he makes a decision"  emphasizes on the object noun 'decision'